# Dynamics crm 365 quick create form get parent entity data

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

When I click on the "New" link in a form's lookup field, the quick create form opens.
I need to get values of the parent form to prefill some fields of the quick create form. This can't be done with mappings (as seen in some posts in this site), since it must only work in the quick create form. How can I do this in javascript? There is no other way except using localStorage?

EDIT:

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attribute name).getValue()
```

does not work

Comment: try `window.top` this shall give you the data example `window.top.sourceentityname`
let me know if this helps

Comment: @sean able to make it work?

Comment: you can answer your solution and close this question. :)

Comment: Ok @Arun Vinoth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices, to achieve this in js.

1. Either in main form scripting you can assign in a global variable and access it in Quick create form. Depends on the version, you may have to manage `formContext` instead of `Xrm.Page`. [Read more](https://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2018/03/17/setting-values-in-a-dynamics-365-ce-quick-create-form-from-the-main-form/)

   ```
    var setValsForQuickCreate = function(){
      window.top.attributename = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_attributename").getValue();
    }

    var setValFromMainForm = function(){
      Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_attributename").setValue(window.top.attributename);
    }
   ```
2. Otherwise, you can query using the web api on form load, filter it based on parent lookup value mapped and fill the fields. You can create a separate library/method for registering in QC form only or check only if it is Quick create form and execute it.

Comment: I used my solution with local storage, but there were problems, because I couldn't  always reset the values of the variables, so if open the contact quick create form from another entity, it takes the value present in local storage, that is an error. I tried the first solution that you propose, but also window.top is a global variable, so difficult to control, and the problem was the same when quick creating a contact from another record. About your second solution, could you please tell me how to get the ID of the parent in the quick create form,in order to use it in the web api? @Arun Vinoth

Comment: @Sean this should help - https://himbap.com/blog/?p=2874

Comment: You should have the parent lookup already filled in the form when it’s opened from subgrid inside parent form through relationship mapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here is another way to find the parent record Id: https://butenko.pro/2020/09/15/js-how-to-get-the-originating-record-reference-in-the-form-script-of-the-quick-create-form/. @Arun Vinoth

Comment: But unfortunately, no way to get the parent data in the quick create form, is the parent form is in New mode. @Arun Vinoth

Comment: Session storage could do the trick.